# How does one get the text from html while ignoring formatting tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The following code is used to grab continuous segments of text from within html.

```
    for text in soup.find_all_next(text=True):
        if isinstance(text, Comment):
            # We found a comment, ignore
            continue
        if not text.strip():
            # We found a blank text, ignore
            continue
        # Whatever is left must be good
        print(text)
```

Text items are broken up by structure tags like `<div>` or `<br>` but also formatting tags like `<em>` and `<strong>`. This causes me some inconvenience in further parsing of the text and I would like to be able to grab continuous text items while ignoring any formatting tags interior to the text.

For example, `soup.find_all_next(text=True)` would take the html code `<div>This is <em>important</em> text</div>` and return a single string, `This is important text` instead of three strings, `This is`, `important`, and `text`.

I'm not sure if that's clear... Let me know if it's not.

**EDIT:** The reason I'm walking through the html text item by text item is that I'm only beginning the walk after I see a specific "begin" comment tag and I'm stopping when I reach a specific "end" comment tag. Are there any solutions that work within this context of needing to walk item by item? The full code I'm using is below.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for instanceBegin in soup.find_all(text=isBeginText):
    # We found a start comment, look at all text and comments:
    for text in instanceBegin.find_all_next(text=True):
        # We found a text or comment, examine it closely
        if isEndText(text):
            # We found the end comment, everybody out of the pool
            break
        if isinstance(text, Comment):
            # We found a comment, ignore
            continue
        if not text.strip():
            # We found a blank text, ignore
            continue
        # Whatever is left must be good
        print(text)
```

Where the two functions `isBeginText(text)` and `isEndText(text)` return true if the string passed to them matches my starting or ending comment tags.

Comment: How do you want to handle a situation where you have two nested block-level tags? Say e.g. `<div>A<p>B</p>C</div>`. What would you want? In any case, the way I see it, is that you should check whether the current tag has any descendants. If so, check (recursively) if those descendants are of the "formatting" type (note that this is subjective: you consider `em` to be one of those, but not `br`) and if they are, remove the formatting tags, but preserve the inner HTML. Perhaps I'm not understanding your problem fully, but would that not solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. Actually, I don't care about any formatting besides preserving basic sentence structure. I'm fine to ignore `<br>`, `<p>`, etc. as long as sentences are preserved (i.e., words don't get smushed together). I'm aware of the `soup.get_text()` method but I'm not sure how to work that into my specific constraints regarding beginning and ending tags (see edit on my original question).

Comment: @OliverW. You bet: The beginning tag is a comment tag, `<!-- Begin -->`, and the ending tag is also a comment tag, `<!-- End -->`. I want all the text between these two comment tags. If there is a new line or a break I'm happy to have it replaced with a space so long as it preserves complete sentences and words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `find_all_next` twice, once for each of the beginning and ending tag and taking the difference of the two generated lists?

As an example, I'll use a modified version of the `html_doc` from [the documentation of BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<!-- START--><a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p><!-- END -->

<p class="story">...</p>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))

# Step 1: find the beginning and ending markers
node_start = [ cmt for cmt in comments if cmt.string == " START" ][0]
node_end = [ cmt for cmt in comments if cmt.string == " END " ][0]

# Step 2, subtract the 2nd list of strings from the first
all_text = node_start.find_all_next(text=True)
all_after_text = node_end.find_all_next(text=True)

subset = all_text[:-(len(all_after_text) + 1)]
print(subset)

# ['Lacie', ' and\n', 'Tillie', ';\nand they lived at the bottom of a well.']
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes to try this out.

Comment: This works beautifully! Wow. I had to mod it a bit to cram it into my code but the output not only preserves sentence structure but also formatting. I could write this straight to a file if I wanted. Thanks mate! The only problem is that it reads comments as well as text. Can comments be excluded from the search in the `find_all_next` method?

Comment: Perhaps I can use the `extract` method to yank comments (except the two I need) from the selected body of text? I'll try that.

Comment: That did it. After we make a list of comments with `soup.findAll` I added the line `[cmt.extract() for cmt in comments if cmt.string != start and cmt.string != end]` where start and end are the strings for the start and end comments. I learned some new stuff tonight. You're a wizard, thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I do want to call out a possible alternative for future viewers of this question (what I had before Oliver W.'s excellent solution) and that is Aaron Swartz' html2text. It produces an excellent reduction of html to text in markdown language. It works great but is not quite the best solution for what I was doing here. Just FYI.

Answer (score 4):

If you grab the parent element containing your children elements and do `get_text()`, BeautifulSoup will strip out all html tags for you and only return a continuous string of text.

You can find an example [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: I should have noted, I suppose, that this all has to happen between two specific "begin" and "end" comments. That's why I'm walking through the html item by item.

Comment: If I used `get_text()` on the whole html file I would get a bunch of garbage that I don't want from the headers and footers. I've revised my original question to include this context.